# SQL Server: compare two tables and populate flag column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to populate flag column after comparing data from two tables.
i have tables A and B.

Table A:

```
NAME----PHONE-----ID1---------ID2   
MAT------123456-----0.123-----2.123
NICK-----234672----123-------234
SAM-----111111-----456------987
```

> Table B columns are 
>   ID_A, ID_B, ID_C, ID_D,,,so on.. and has data similar to ID1 and ID2 on Table A

If ID1 or ID2 from Table A matches any values on Table b for respective row then put 'Y' on the flag column of Table B.
requirement is pretty straight but i am not sure how to start coding .any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a `case` statement and `exists` clause:

```
select b.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from tableA a
                          where a.id1 in (b.id_a, b.id_b, b.id_c, b.id_d) or
                                a.id2 in (b.id_a, b.id_b, b.id_c, b.id_d)
                         )
             then 'Y'
             else 'N'
        end) as flag
from tableB b;
```

EDIT:

If you actually want an update:

```
update b
    set flag = (case when exists (select 1
                                  from tableA a
                                  where a.id1 in (b.id_a, b.id_b, b.id_c, b.id_d) or
                                        a.id2 in (b.id_a, b.id_b, b.id_c, b.id_d)
                                 )
                     then 'Y'
                     else 'N'
                end);
```

Comment: thank you for a quick reply. your query makes sense i have not doubt on it  but is there anyway we can get all columns dynamically and compare with id1 because table b has about 45 columns and it is not possible to hard code. sorry i should have mentioned that.

Comment: @sqlsean . . . You need to hardcode it.  That's what happens when you store data in a denormalized form.  You can get the list of columns using `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'tableA'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  b
SET     Flag = CASE WHEN EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT x.ID FROM 
            (
                SELECT b.ID_A UNION ALL 
                SELECT b.ID_B UNION ALL 
                SELECT b.ID_C UNION ALL 
                SELECT b.ID_D UNION ALL 
                SELECT b.ID_E
            ) x(ID) WHERE x.ID IS NOT NULL
            INTERSECT
            SELECT y.ID FROM dbo.TableA a CROSS APPLY 
            (
                SELECT a.ID1 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT a.ID2
            ) y(ID) WHERE y.ID IS NOT NULL
        ) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM    dbo.TableB b;
```